# How can i get first and last day of current week in ISO Date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

$gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),$lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: i tried to rung mongodb query to get data between last sunday and next sunday of the week.

Comment: Both requirements (first and last day of a week, date in iso format) are not new. You should be able to find enough resources to get you (at least) started.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: @str this is in different format, i want it in ISO date format.

Comment: You don't need to care about the format at all. Just use the JavaScript date object, the MongoDB driver handles it correctly.

Comment: thnak you! it's work properly

Answer (score 0):

You may get the day of the week by calling [.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) on the date object. Once you have the day of the week, rest are arithmetic operations.

To convert Date to ISODateFormat you can use [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
    var dateForCalculation = new Date();
    var prevSunday = new Date(dateForCalculation.setDate(dateForCalculation.getDate()-dateForCalculation.getDay())).toISOString();
    var nextSunday = new Date(dateForCalculation.setDate(dateForCalculation.getDate()+7)).toISOString();

    console.log(prevSunday);
    console.log(nextSunday);
```